# How can I make my dynamically sized lightboxes overflow/scroll correctly?

Tags: css, dynamic, overflow, lightbox, border-box

I'm sure I'm doing something obvious wrong, but I haven't been able to figure it out. My lightboxes size dynamically (percentage width), and I want the content within the lightboxes to scroll vertically as needed on smaller screens without displacing the border (actually a box-shadow) around the content.

As an added caveat, I need the "container" div to have dynamic height. When I set the container div to height: 100%, the lightbox functions like I want (see code below), but when I remove the height setting, the overflow no longer works right.

This demo of my lightboxes in action should help clarify my question:

http://viewer.zmags.com/publication/a82492b9?viewType=pubPreview

Here's my CSS:

```
html{
height: 100%;}

body {
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background: #FF0000;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;}

div.container {
background-color: #6d6d6d;
padding: 20px;
height: 100%; <!-- I want to remove this, but can't figure out a way to get the same functionality without it -->
overflow: hidden;}

div.content {
background-color: #6d6d6d;
overflow: auto;
max-height: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;}

div#tab1 {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset, 0 0 0 4px #be854C inset;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;}
```

And my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container" id="tab1">
<div class="content">
<p>Lightbox content here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the bottom of your `.content` is getting div is getting cut off because of the size of the iframe, at least in the preview.

Comment: It doesn't get cut off in the example on the left, but it does in the example on the right. Only difference is the one line of code (removal of "height: 100;" on the container div.  Any thoughts on how i can make it not get cut off in the example on the right? Also, sadly, the iFrame settings are outside my area of control... but I can assure you they are handled the same for both examples.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser support requirements allow it, consider absolutely positioning your `.container` div, and setting its top, left, etc appropriately:

```
div.container {
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

That has some downsides if you're trying to position other elements on the page, but for a lightbox, it's a reasonable solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So here's my dilemma. When I use your method, the result is basically identical to when I set height: 100% -- meaning it causes the same problem for me. The overflow and scroll is handled well, but I want the height of the div to adjust with the amount of content. When I take away the bottom: 0; to allow the height to flow freely, it's just like the right-hand lightbox in my example below -- the overflow and scrolling break.